# RecyclerView change image on click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm making ola like car selecting function. I've an API from which I'm getting car type, selected image link and unselected image link. I'm using recyclerview with text and image view for that. While creating the recyclerview I'm selecting first position and displaying `hover-image` to show selected. When I select another image it changes to selected image but the previously selected one doesn't changes to unselected image. This means that the for loop is not working. But when I printed the url link for the unselected images the url link shows correct. Then why its not showing in Picasso.

```html
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Model> arrayList;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Model> arrayList) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView txt;
        ImageView image;
        LinearLayout LL_root;

        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            LL_root = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.LL_root);
            LL_root.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.LL_root:
                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                    System.out.println("sammy_onclick_position "+pos);



                    for(int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++){
                        if(pos!=i){
                            Picasso.with(context).load(arrayList.get(i).getImage()).into(image);
                            System.out.println("sammy_unselected_image "+arrayList.get(i).getImage());
                        }
                    }
                    Picasso.with(context).load(arrayList.get(pos).getSelectedImage()).into(image);
                    System.out.println("sammy_selected_image "+arrayList.get(pos).getSelectedImage());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Model model = arrayList.get(position);
        holder.txt.setText(model.getTitle());
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(model.getImage())){
            if(position==0)
                Picasso.with(context).load(model.getSelectedImage()).into(holder.image);
            else
                Picasso.with(context).load(model.getImage()).into(holder.image);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried - `notifyDataSetChanged()` ?

Comment: I tried notifyDataSetChanged() on click in last. But it only calls `onBindViewHolder` and this again makes the first position selected as in `onBindViewHolder` I'm displaying the selected image in first position only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the reference to the selected position in your adapter and then check if the current item is selected in the `onBindViewHolder` :

Create a global field :

```
int selectedPos = 0;
```

In you `onClick` :

```
selectedPos = getAdapterPosition();
```

And in your `onBindViewHolder` do the check this way :

```
if(position == selectedPos) {    
   Picasso.with(context).load(model.getSelectedImage()).into(holder.image);
} else {    
   Picasso.with(context).load(model.getImage()).into(holder.image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the adapter with the second item being selected.